# Pandas: Updating Pivot_table margins automatically

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table

I have created a pivot_table using the following code:

```
confMatrix_structure = pd.DataFrame({
        'confMatrix_column':['selected','notSelected'],
        'confMatrix_index':['relevant','irrelevant'],
        'confMatrix_dummy_value': [5,10]
    })

confusion_matrix = 
         pd.pivot_table(confMatrix_structure,values='confMatrix_dummy_value',
                                      index=['confMatrix_index'],
             columns=['confMatrix_column'],margins=True,margins_name='total')
```

And the pivot_table looks like this:

[image: Pivot Table]

Now, If I update the table by writing the following code:

```
confusion_matrix.loc['irrelevant','selected']=25
```

After running the above code the table looks like:

[image: After Updating Pivot_table]

As you can see from the picture the cell has been updated by the margins/total hasn't updated to reflect this change.

I have written the following function and using it to update the total values after each update in cell:

```
def updateConfMatrix(): 
   confusion_matrix.loc['irrelevant','total'] =confusion_matrix.loc['irrelevant'].sum() -confusion_matrix.loc['irrelevant','total']
   confusion_matrix.loc['relevant','total'] = confusion_matrix.loc['relevant'].sum() - confusion_matrix.loc['relevant','total']
   confusion_matrix.loc['total','notSelected'] = confusion_matrix.loc[:,'notSelected'].sum() - confusion_matrix.loc['total','notSelected']
   confusion_matrix.loc['total','selected'] = confusion_matrix.loc[:,'selected'].sum() - confusion_matrix.loc['total','selected']
   confusion_matrix.loc['total','total'] = confusion_matrix.loc['total'].sum() - confusion_matrix.loc['total','total']
```

This would work fine for small data but I have thousands of data. So, Is there a simpler and faster way to do this update? or make this process automatically so that pivot_table recalculates it's total/margins after updating any cell.

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic function that works for any number of rows and columns.

```
def updateConfMatrix():
    cols = list(confusion_matrix)
    cols.remove('total') # exclude the total column
    for col in list(confusion_matrix)[-1]: 
        confusion_matrix.loc['total', col] = confusion_matrix[col].sum() - confusion_matrix.loc['total', col]
    confusion_matrix.total = confusion_matrix[cols].sum(axis=1)
```